# Why do cars still use mechanical blinker relays?

Tags: wiring, lights, turn-signal, relay, electronics

I think the electronic relays may be cheaper; and having less moving parts they are theoretically less prone to break.

So, why do cars still use mechanical relays for turning lights?

Comment: You also need to consider that the high wattage of an incandescent turn signal all but requires a mechanical relay.  To replace _just_ the mechanical relay you end up needing LED bulbs all around the car, an electronic timer relay, and some sort of speaker to provide the clicking sound and those costs add up.

Comment: It is not a requisite they are LED bulbs; you can also control blinking patterns on incandescent bulbs using electronics!

Comment: A turn signal bulb will draw about 2 amps.  There are at least 4 of them on a car, and with hazard lights on they all light up at the same time.  That's 8 amps, probably closer to 10 amps depending on the bulb, wire losses, and the other two small indicator bulbs in the instrument cluster.  I'm not saying you can't find a solid state, 10A relay, but they are going to be very expensive compared to tried and proven mechanical relay that has a cost of less than $1.

Comment: @JPhi1618 It amazes me why an electronic relay has to be expensive! Do you have sources of prices for them? In these days, when silicon chips are everywhere due to their low costs, why that? And I think producing one chip has costs; but reproducing it in millions is virtually costless! It is even more automatizable to produce integrated circuits, than mechanical parts, as instead of doing precision engineering for joining together moving mechanical parts, you will only cut a silicon wafer! And better, you could even do better, by integrating the blinking functionality on an ECU!

Answer (score 8):

I can think of several reasons straight away:

- Cheap
- Easy to replace
- Have a very distinctive click that makes it obvious when they are on, and when a bulb has failed
- Are very well understood
- Anyone can fit one without needing to understand much about electronics

Comment: Don't some BCM's have some indicator light features now?

Comment: Yes, more and more are moving to on-board indicator circuitry. But still plenty of old-school relays :-)

Comment: Indeed.  It's comforting analogue sound that's emitted and surprisingly reliable.  I think I had 320K miles on a Toyota 22R 4X4 and I never swapped a blinker relay.  That's a lot of work for a bi-metal strip.

Comment: A mechanical relay is cheaper and much more reliable than the newer designs being built into circuit boards. I have first hand experience of these circuit boards going bad and costing upwards of $200 when a relay would have been less than $100.

Comment: The majority of the reasons you pointed out can be accomplished by an electronic counterpart. 
**Cheap:** with today's electronic knowledge, only producing the first one is has significant costs, its reproduction in millions of chips is virtually costless; 
**Easy to replace:** this is a question of design; it can be *designed* to be easy to replace — and it is even easier to as electronics can be made smaller and more custom (compare modern vs old mobile phone chargers) to specific needs; 
*(cont.=>)*

Comment: *(=>cont.)* **Distinctive click:** can also be easily made by electronics. **See when a bulb has failed** a single light on information panel can convey this information to the car's user. 
Ok, I give you some credit on the **click sound**/**bulb fail diagnostic**, but ...
**Are very well understood:** How they work, yes, I agree with you. Not the same in the electronic case;
**Anyone can fit one:** Again, a question of *design*. I think the electronic relay as a black box, with a few pins to connect it to the car, in the same way of the mechanical one.

Comment: @DucatiKiller: Just for clarifying what is BCM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_control_module

Comment: @racefever: But wouldn't  it be expectable te electronic one to be more reliable, as it has no moving parts? I am just comparing computers' SSD  drives to HDD drives ...

Comment: @sergiol: Reliability is kind of irrelevant when there are 1960's relays still functioning today. Also, note that, until recently, HDDs were more reliable than SSDs because it was an older, more mature technology.

Comment: @MichaelS: May be that is not the analogy I wanted to transmit in my message. For example. compare USB pen drives and memory flash cards to CD drives and floppy diskettes. Which of them have been more reliable? Without any doubt, the ones that have not mechanical parts!

Comment: As an off topic aside - while I agree mechanical parts are not as likely to be able to last as long, in reality, build standards were much higher in most consumer industries back in the day, so mechanical parts still seem to last longer than electronic equivalents in a lot of situations

Comment: @sergiol Not at all. Electronic ones are considered black boxes. You can't really service them. They can fail if the supplier provided a bad batch of ICs or any other component. A mechanical relay just works.

Comment: @sergiol: My point is that even if there's a theoretical better item, it doesn't mean it's necessarily better in practice, right now. Mechanical relays have like 150 years of industry built around them. That kind of maturity can make a huge difference. My secondary point is that I have floppy drives from the 90s that still work, and relays from the 60s that still work. At that point, you're not really going to get better sales by making the product even more reliable. It's not a bad thing; it's just not that important either.

Comment: Just want to jump in here. There are potential weight savings in moving to ICs and electronic relays. Consider that soon cars will be using micro 3 fuses. All in the name of reducing weight and gaining MPG.

Comment: On the topic of reliability. There is such a thing as good enough. Electronic relays may be able to be made more reliable than electromechanical ones. However, given that electromechanical relays almost never fail unless the powersupply is bad, why bother? they're good enough and cheap to manufacture. And a bad powersupply will kill electronic relays just as well